# Every trail can be extended to an Euler tour

Tags: graph-theory

> Let G be a nontrivial and eulerian graph, and let $v \in V(G)$. Prove that every trail of $G$ with origin $v$ can be extended to an Euler tour of $G$ if and only if $G - v$ is a forest.

I've tried various approaches to this problem, but nothing worked. Any hint/solution? Thanks!

Comment: A forest is a disjunct union of trees, a tree is a graph in which each pair of vertices are connected through an unique path. How can there by cycles in your graph G? Let alone Eulerian cycles, am I missing something here?

Comment: @Auberon: $G$ is Eulerian, $G-v$ is a forest. If you want an example take $G$ to be a cycle, and $v$ any vertex on the cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Rightarrow$: Suppose $G-v$ is not a forest, i.e. it has a cycle $C$.
The graph $G-E(C)$ ($E(C)$ is the edges of $C$) still has all vertices of even degree, so
it has a closed Eulerian trail $T$. We can view $T$ as a trail in $G$ that starts (and ends) in $v$.
Since all edges incident to $v$ are already used in $T$, we cannot extend this to an Euler tour.
Contradiction.

$\Leftarrow$: Let $S$ be a trail starting at $v$ and let $T$ be a maximal trail extending $S$
($T$ may be equal to $S$). Because all vertices of $G$ have even degree,
$T$ must also end in $v$ and $T$ must have used all edges incident with $v$.
But then $G-E(T)$ is also a graph that has all vertices of even degree and none
of its edges are incident with $v$. Such a graph decomposes into cycles and all of them miss $v$.
Since $G-v$ is a forest there are no cycles in $G-v$, we conclude that $T$ must already contain
all edges of $G$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm just having trouble accepting one part: "Because all vertices of G have even degree, T must also end in v and T must have used all edges incident with v" why is this true?

Comment: That $T$ must end in $v$ is a standard argument when proving that an even graph has an Eulerian cycle, so I'll assume that you have trouble with the other part. And that is easy: if not all edges incident with $v$ are used, then you can prolong $T$ by leaving $v$ over an unused edge.